# Why is Angular reflect polyfill required for JIT

Tags: angular

In the [Angular browser support page](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support), it says with regard to the JIT compilation and the ES7/reflect polyfill:

> Can remove if you always use AOT and only use Angular decorators.

Two things are unclear to me about this:

1. Why doesn't AOT require the use of reflection? isn't reflection needed to read metadata for dependency injection?
2. What does it mean "only use Angular decorators"?

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't AOT require the use of reflection? isn't reflection needed
>   to read metadata for dependency injection?

Yes, AOT works with compiled version that doesn't require reflection. AOT compiler statically resolves all metadata and converts it to factories that include all they need to render.

> What does it mean "only use Angular decorators"?

You have to include that polyfill if use any non-Angular specific decorator since AOT compiler only transforms decorators which it knows, i.e. `@Component`, `@Input` `@NgModule` etc. Also it removes those decorators from bundle. For other decorators, that will be executed at runtime, we have to include that polyfill.

Comment: Just to clarify. Decorators are a TypeScript feature, and that feature requires the polyfil. This isn't an Angular limitation, but AOT effectively *removes* all the decorators when it compiles everything. So you are basically disabling support for decorators according to TypeScript if you remove the polyfill. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html